# How to obtain individual estimates (slopes/intercepts) in proc mixed (SAS)

Tags: sas, statistics, mixed-models

I'm interested in seeing how sedentary behaviors change throughout time (Time 1, 2, 3) and see in a second step how it relates to mental health.

Thus, I would like to obtain an estimate (slope/intercept) for each subject to allow me to do the 2nd step. I can't find online how to do it (not sure what to search for).

Here's my code so far, which gives me 2 estimates (boys and girls); I would rather have an estimate for every participant.

```
ods output LSMeans=Means1;
proc mixed data=sb.LFcomplete method=ml covtest;
class SexeF time;
model CompDay = Time SexeF Time*SexeF;
repeated time;
lsmeans time*sexeF;
run;
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please check this website for a similar example: 
https://www.stat.ncsu.edu/people/davidian/courses/st732/examples/ex10_1.sas

The professor was using HLM for longitudinal data analysis. He used gender like your SexeF, age like your Time, and child as ID. The tricky part is when he was organizing the random effect file, he sorted ID and created Gender (Group or your SexeF) for subsequent merging with the fixed effects file. If your current ID variable is not aligned with your SexeF, you may sort your SexeF and create a new ID variable in SPSS before you import your data in SPSS.